# Dynamic Insert in SQL without Field Names

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I am looking for a solution to insert some data in a a table using 3 parameters, the first one is the table name, and the second is a List with a class that has the name and value property.
I have a partially solution (below) for this, but i don't think it is recommended, so, I looking for a best practice to do it.

If is possible, I'd like a suggestion to create this using parameters in order to avoid injections.

```
private void InsertMetada(string deviceType, List<DeviceFields> deviceFields)
 {
 DataBaseConnection database = new DataBaseConnection ();
 database.Open();
 StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
 stb.Append(string.Format("INSERT INTO DEVICE_{0} ( ", deviceType.ToString().ToUpper()));
 foreach (var item in deviceFields)
 {
    strb.Append(string.Format(" {0}, ",item.name.ToString()));            
 }
 stb.Append(") VALUES ( ");
 foreach (var item in deviceFields)
 {
    strb.Append(string.Format(" '{0}', ", item.value.ToString()));
 }
 strb.Append(")");
 database.executeQuery(strb.ToString());
 database.Close();
 }
```

**EDITED:** I don't think I was very clear in my question.
In this case, the `DeviceFields.item.name` has the same name of the table field.

What I am looking for is guarantee create different Device properties, for different Device Types in different tables.

Maybe my point of view is not the right one, but I thought if I have separated tables I could perform a fast search.
In this example my Table (DEVICE_KEYBOARD) looks like this:

```
> FIELD NAME  | TYPE
 -------------|---------
 language     | varchar   
 key          | varchar   
 isMultimedia | varchar
 deviceID     | varchar
```

and the list looks like

```
> DeviceFields[0]:
 name = language  
 value = en-us 

> DeviceField[1]:  
 name = key  
 value = 102

> DeviceField[2]:  
 name = isMultimedia  
 value = Yes

> DeviceField[3]:  
 name = deviceID  
 value = 0000-0000-00000-00000
```

And the second Table, for example is like:

```
 TABLE DEVICE_SPEAKER

> FIELD NAME   | TYPE
 --------------|---------
 rms           | varchar   
 remoteControl | varchar   
 subwoofer     | varchar
 deviceID       | varchar
```

It has all device fields in the first table, but this properties are specific for each kind of device...
The idea is to have opportunity to create a new property crating a new column, when the ADD button is clicked by the user, in this table, with the prefix "DEVICE_{DEVICE TYPE}"

I can list all fields when I prepare the List, my question is to know if is there a best option to create this stuff, and what could be safe and fast.

Comment: Just wondering: Do you have the power to change the DB design (e.g. to store the device type in a field)? What you are trying looks hard from my point of view. Sanitizing the input by hand may be a way to go, but I barely think this is recommended practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with creating a stored procedure. If you need your INSERT statements to be dynamic, this can be done within the sproc.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Building_Dynamic_SQL.aspx

Personally, I hate dynamic SQL in stored procedures and some would say it is bad practice, but sometimes it is the best option depending on your circumstances. I'm just throwing it out there as an option.

Comment: With dynamic SQL in an sproc, the SQL injection problem would not be solved yet, would it? Or does SQL server do some input sanitizing? In general, however, I'd also tend to build a sproc, thus +1.

Comment: SQL injection would still be a risk, but can be managed if the procedure is carefully scripted. For example, if expecting a numeric input, use the INT data type rather than VARCHAR or some other string type. For the text-based data type inputs, the values should be escaped. And it goes without saying that appropriate permissions need to be set up in the database so that the login that the website is using only has the power to do what it needs to do and nothing more. Here's some good info on the topic: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection. Hence, why I hate dynamic SQL :)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to create a stored procedure and the parameter names would match each deviceField's name. The downside is that the stored proc parameter must match (case insensitive) your field names.

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement. I'd build parameterised query in the form

```
Insert into {TableName} ({ColumnName1,ColumnName2..ColumnNameN}) 
Values(@ColumnName1,@ColumnName2.. @ColumnNameN)
```

Don't know homogenous your data is if you could do the above once per table, then add the parameters to the command object, then iterate through your list and set the params to the values.

Not brilliant but better. I've used the above technique even with no column names in some legacy stuff where the table is basically a property bag.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!